# How can I select the values of the input checked rows into a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I am pretty new in JavaScript development and I have the following situation.

Into a JSP page I have a table having the following strutcure

```
<TABLE class=standard-table-cls id=senttable>
    <TR class=odd>
        <TD>
            <INPUT name=item type=checkbox alt=Cancella value=68662>
        </TD>

        <TD> ......................................... </TD>
        <TD> ......................................... </TD>
        <TD> ......................................... </TD>
    <TR>

    <TR class=even>
        <TD>
            <INPUT name=item type=checkbox alt=Cancella value=68661>
        </TD>

        <TD> ......................................... </TD>
        <TD> ......................................... </TD>
        <TD> ......................................... </TD>
    <TR>

    <TR class=odd> ....................................................</TR>
    <TR class=even> ....................................................</TR>
    <TR class=odd> ....................................................</TR>
    <TR class=even> ....................................................</TR>
    ........................................................................
    ........................................................................

</TABLE>
```

As you can see in this table there is a specific column (the first one) that represent a **checkbox** that the user can check. This column have always setted the **value** that represent the ID of the object represented by the current row (in the previous example: **68662** and **68661**, etcetc)

What I need to do is create a JavaScript function that create a string representing the concatenation of all the values of the **value** field of the checked rows.

For example if the first 2 rows are checked this string have to be something like: **68662-68661**

How can I do something like this?

Tnx

Comment: `How can I do something like this?` what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you post your *actual* HTML. A single row will do.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what do you exactly mean? what I have to post?

Comment: I mean that it's hard to know how to select the values of fields that aren't shown in your question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If the user check the checkbox the value inside the value field is append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method in combination with [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```javascript
var values = $('#senttable :checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join('-');
```

Comment: ok now I will try but I have some doubt about your code. Where have I to declare it? Into a standard JavaScript?

Comment: Execute this code when you need to get this concatenated string. Check the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uztfusvv/

Comment: Ok tnx, it wors fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your html markup a little bit like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="68662" alt=Cancella>
```

Then you can call the following javascript function to get the **'-'** separated string that you need.

```
    function getString()
    {  
      $('input[name="item[]"]:checked').each(function() {

                var returnString="";

                 if($(this).is(':checked'))
                 {
                      var chkboxval = $(this).val();
                      returnString= chkboxval + "-" + returnString 
                  }
            }

          );

      return returnString;
    }
```